# Performance cost of import * as something vs import { func1, func2...func100 }

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm just curious if anyone knows the performance hit during build/run-time cost in node/javascript using es6, if you import * as something from './functions.js'

The reason is I'm noticing that some of the files I'm working with are importing a lot of functions(20-40) and looks cleaner to just do import *, but curious if anyone knows if this will cause things to be slower?

I've tried both and it works but doesn't really notice a difference in build or run time.  I've searched online but mainly threads that talk about the difference of the two but not if long term it will/can impact performance.

```
//
import { func1, func2, func3 } from './functions.js'


func1(1);
func2(1);
func3(1);
```

vs

```
//
import * as functions from './functions.js'


functions.func1(1);
functions.func2(1);
functions.func3(1);
```

let's assume there are 30 functions that I'm importing so if I manually import all of them, the imports can go on for 30+lines instead of 1 line.

both work functionally but what I'm after here is if using * is wrong and won't scale?

Don't see any performance issue either way.  Probably cuz file isn't big enough, but would be great to know general guidance on when to use one vs the other.  I know I can create a default import and import that, but let's say that isn't an option to create a default.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter as you are using babel and it will be compiled down to the best solution. So, I would say that in the long run, it won't matter. Also, be it 30 or 300 functions, the difference in performance will be very insignificant.

Comment: It's just property assignments.  The exports object from the module you're importing has all the exports as properties on an object. So, if you import only a few, you're only assigning a few of those properties to local variables or local properties.  If you `import *`, you're assigning all of them.  So, any performance difference would likely be small and related to the difference between copying three properties of an object vs. copying 300 properties.

Comment: As always with performance questions, if it really matters to you, set up a test with a setup that is relevant to your situation and measure the actual difference.  There is no substitute for measuring.  Theoretical questions about performance issues are often completely worthless, partly because even if something turns out to be 2x faster, the overall operation might be so fast that the 2x difference is irrelevant to anything you care about.  Plus, import in node.js is usually a startup-only issue and startup time is not usually particularly important and is usually gated by I/O.